# Repeat R script for many times and save results from every repitation to one matrix

Tags: r

I run my script one time for example and firstly I obtain one matrix `mat_temp` based on randomization functions as follows:

```
Time Measurement
22:35:00 0
22:40:00 0
22:45:00 0
22:50:00 0
22:55:00 0
23:00:00 0
23:05:00 0
23:10:00 0.11
23:15:00 0.28
23:20:00 0
23:25:00 0.22
23:30:00 0.08
23:35:00 0.08
23:40:00 0
23:45:00 0.11
23:50:00 0.06
23:55:00 0.23
```

and then I get the results for

```
(1). sum = 1.17
(2). n_wet = 8 (measurement > 0)
(3). n_dry = 9 (measurement == 0)
(4). intensity = 0.15
```

The data in `mat_temp` and the corresponding results change every time if I run the script. And I want to run it for 100 times and average the results. I found the possible solution like:

```
 lapply(1:100,function(n)source("my_script.R"))
```

I tested it with two times and it gave results as follows, where the two values: `2.128558` and `2.160195` are only the results for `intensity`. There was not results for the others: `sum`, `n_wet` and `n_dry`

```
 > lapply(1:2,function(n)source("my_script.R"))
[[1]]
[[1]]$value
[1] 2.128558

[[1]]$visible
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]]$value
[1] 2.160195

[[2]]$visible
[1] FALSE
```

**Can you explain why it only gives one result and how can I manage to average the results after I run my script for 100 times?**

Comment: Hello R user,  You need to provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for how to do this

Comment: We'll need to know the contents of "my_script.R" in order to help you with this

Comment: Hello, thank you for the replies but my script has hundreds of lines and it can only be run based on one .txt file. I am very new in R and I am not sure I can provide my script here with the .txt file. I just need to run the whole script for 100 times and average the four final results as I explained in the question. It would be very helpful if you can give some possible solutions and I can try in my script. Thank you again!